# Force extra ticks to end of graph in Highstock

Tags: highcharts

I have a graph in Highstock that has dual Y-Axes and Flags for annotations. The flags can be placed beyond the last point on the X-Axis that has data, but no additional ticks are formed to indicate roughly where the flag has been placed. Is there any way to force Highstock to add additional ticks beyond the ones specified in the data?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different timezones cause Highstock ticks to display oddly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813322/different-timezones-cause-highstock-ticks-to-display-oddly)

Comment: I don't believe this to be a duplicate. This question deals with the possibility of adding further ticks beyond the final data point without having to add extra pseudo data onto the data set passed into Highstock. From reading the api documentation, it seems that pointRange governs the distance between points of existing data, but wouldn't add additional points beyond it.

Comment: But when you flag is out of range, then xAxis is scaled to include this point.

Comment: The xAxis itself is scaled, but the ticks are not. I don't know exactly how highstock calculates tick placement but I believe flag data points are not included in the calculation as they are expected to mark points on a graph and therefor should fall within existing data. As you can see from the image, the tick marks do not go beyond  00:00, which is the last point of data I provide for both the bar and line graphs and is what led me to the conclusion regarding flags.