# Different timezones cause Highstock ticks to display oddly

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highstock for a long term activity graph that can be drilled down to a 1 day view. At that level, however, Highstock begins to place tick marks in an oddly dense pattern in timezones that have had the day turn over, as seen in the image below. I am using UTC times for my data points but letting highstock convert them to local time.

[image]

Comment: Please provide us with your code, or with a JS Fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange) parameter

Comment: wouldn't setting pointRange mean that when the chart was zoomed out, the points would become incredibly dense, to the point of unreadability? I'm using highcharts because it seems to calculate appropriate point ranges on the fly based on data point density.